# Chrome issue changing source of audio element when using AudioContext

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

The Audio sound is distorded (like playing twice at the same time or something like that) when I change its source dynamically, if the element was used in the createMediaElementSource of an AudioContext.

Here is a minimalist example of the error: http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/wkFpv/ (It works well at first but it is going crazy when you click a link to change the source).

```javascript
var audio = document.getElementById('music');
var actx = new webkitAudioContext();
var node, processor = actx.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);
processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) { /* STUFF */ };
processor.connect(actx.destination);
audio.addEventListener('canplay', canPlayFired);
function canPlayFired(event)
{
    node = actx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    node.connect(processor);
    audio.removeEventListener('canplay', canPlayFired);
}
$('a.changeMusic').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    audio.src = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

If I put `node.disconnect(0);` before `audio.src = ...` it works but the data is no more processed. I tried a lot of thing like creating a new context but it seems not to erase the previously set javascript node.

Do you know how I could fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at this: [jsbin.com/acolet/1](http://jsbin.com/acolet/1)

It seems to be doing the same thing you are looking for.

I found this from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958175/html5-audio-api-audio-resources-unavailable-for-audiocontext-construction).

Comment: Thanks for linking to my previous answer! I believe the thing he's missing is reconnecting the new `MediaElementSource` node after disconnecting the old one.

Comment: Thanks, following your exemple I now recreate the whole audio element and it works correctly. I just append it to an element on the page to allow the user playing with it. For those who want to do it too, don't forget to put `audio.controls = 'true';` so as to make the element visible